# How to get types from an array of string

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have data imported from a json file and I map through the data to get an array of string.

I get an error `A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.` when writing like this.

I know I cannot use `as const` like this with a variable, but what are other ways I can achieve this?

```
import _data from './data.json'

const locales = _data.map(item => item.code) as const   //['fr-fr', 'es-es']

export type DataType = typeof locales[number]   //want to have 'fr-fr' | 'es-es'
```

Comment: You're expecting to retrieve information of a `.json` file content at compile time. The compiler can impossibly know how to infer that.

Comment: This isn't currently possible; see the linked question and answer for more information, and specifically [ms/TS#32063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063)